# Is there any cool way to express `if x is None: x = self.x` in python class?

Tags: python, class, oop, default-value, instance-variables

I'm just studying python OOP, and truly confused when to use `self` and not.

especially when I want to make a method that defaultly get object instance input and also wanna make it work as a normal method that can get the input of custom parameters,
I get somewhat bothersome to type `if x is None: x = self.x` for all the parameters of the method.

Example is as follows.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class PlusCalculator():
    x: int = 1
    y: int = 2
    result: int = None
    
    def plus(self, x=None, y=None):
        if x is None: x = self.x    ## the bothersome part
        if y is None: y = self.y
        
        result = x + y
        self.result = result        ## also confusing...is it good way?
        
        return result
    
pc = PlusCalculator()
print(pc.plus())
print(pc.plus(4,5))
```

Is there any good way to use instance variables as default value of function parameter??

Comment: @ScaryWombat: That would ignore the instance attribute values in favor of fixed defaults.

Comment: `self.result = result  ## also confusing...is it good way?` - Yes, that's confusing. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Fun fact: there's an open PEP for [late-bound function argument defaults (PEP 671)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0671/), which if accepted would let you write something like `def plus(self, x=>self.x, y=>self.y)`

Comment: What you're using is perfectly fine at this scale. In your real code, are you writing one method that takes a lot of parameters, or multiple methods that take the same parameters? Or something else? Also, are you ever going to be mixing defaults and arguments, like say, `print(pc.plus(4))`? More details about the situation could help us find better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conditional expression is readable, fast, and intuitive-

```
x = self.x if x is None else x
```

Re:

> Is there any good way to use instance variables as default value of function parameter??

Regarding the setting of `self.result`- This should be avoided unless you need to access it as an instance variable later. As such you can simplify this to:

```
@dataclass
class PlusCalculator():
    ...

    def plus(self, x=None, y=None):
        x = self.x if x is None else x
        y = self.y if y is None else y
        return x + y
```

Comment: oh that expression is much cooler than original one. Thanks a lot!

btw, can you explain more about "accessing it as an instance prop"???

Thanks again, Ian.

Comment: Sure- Instance variables are any variables set by `self.<variable> = value`; These live with the instance of the class instance itself. In that case, this would be the calculator instance. If you are saving the result of `plus()` to a variable, then there is no need to store the last result via `self.result = ...` unless it is to be accessed by other methods/means

Answer (score 1):

One cleaner approach would be to create a method decorator such that when the wrapped method is called, arguments with a default value would be applied with values of attributes of the `self` object under the same names as parameters declared with a default value of an object meant as a default value to be replaced. I recommend that this object be a new object (named `DEFAULT` in the following example) dedicated for this purpose instead of `None` so that `None` can actually be used as an intended argument value for the decorated method:

```
from inspect import signature

def default_self(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bound = sig.bind(self, *args, **kwargs)
        bound.apply_defaults()
        for name in names:
            if bound.arguments[name] is DEFAULT:
                bound.arguments[name] = getattr(self, name)
        return method(*bound.args, **bound.kwargs)

    sig = signature(method)
    names = [name for name, param in sig.parameters.items() if param.default is DEFAULT]
    return wrapper

DEFAULT = object()
```

so that:

```
@dataclass
class PlusCalculator:
    x: int = 1
    y: int = 2
    result: int = None

    @default_self
    def plus(self, x=DEFAULT, y=DEFAULT):
        self.result = x + y # an intermediate variable is unnecessary
        return self.result

pc = PlusCalculator()
print(pc.plus())
print(pc.plus(4, 5))
print(pc.plus(y=3))
print(pc.plus(x=2, y=3))
```

outputs:

```
3
9
4
5
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/joPRKD